# I am trying to create a skybox with openGL in C, but am only getting a black screen

Tags: c, opengl, texture-mapping, skybox

I'm trying to create a skybox with OpenGL in C. I have viewed many tutorials and looked at many people's code, and I don't think I've missed anything, and yet get a black screen. Have I gone about the whole thing wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

GLuint texture[6];

/**
 * Init function initializing the background to black.
 */
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();   
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW | GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename, int width, int height)
{
    GLuint texture;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;

    //Open the image file
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    //If it doesn't open just return 0
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Allocate space for data and read
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3);
    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);

    //Close the file
    fclose(file);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );    
    free(data);

    return texture;     
}

void draw()
{
    int width = 512;
    int height = 512;
    int length = 512;

    //start in this coordinates
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    //center the square
    x = x - width / 2;
    y = y - height / 2;
    z = z - length / 2;

    // Bind the BACK texture of the sky map to the BACK side of the cube
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);      
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    glEnd();

    //FRONT
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x, y,  z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z + length); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z + length);
    glEnd();

    //BOTTOM
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);      
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x, y,  z);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y,  z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z + length); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z);
    glEnd();

    //TOP
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);      
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z + length); 
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z);
    glEnd();

    //LEFT
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);      
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x, y + height, z + length); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x, y,  z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x, y,  z);     

    glEnd();

    //RIGHT
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y,  z + length);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z + length); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(x + width, y + height, z);
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    texture[0] = LoadTexture("back.bmp", 512, 512);
    /*texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGl_texture
    {
        "back.bmp",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
    };*/
    texture[1] = LoadTexture("front.bmp", 512, 512);
    texture[2] = LoadTexture("left.bmp", 512, 512);
    texture[3] = LoadTexture("right.bmp", 512, 512);
    texture[4] = LoadTexture("cesped.bmp", 512, 512);
    texture[5] = LoadTexture("top.bmp", 512, 512);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

    draw();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("blah");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Few things to try 1. You are creating textures again and again in display function. This is not the way. Create textures in Init function and just use them in display 2. You have not set idleFunc and not called glutPostRedisplay  in draw function

Comment: please describe what you've done, may be you could try to debug and locate the problem piece?

Comment: Does changing the clear colour make any difference?. Also, have you confirmed that the textures are loading correctly? If you can see the clear colour, then there is something wrong with your mesh drawing. If it is still black, then the textures have not been created successfully.

Comment: Your projections seems not to fit your skybox. In z-direction, for example, the visible range is specified from 1.5 to 20, but your skybox is drawn from -256 to 256, which is behind the farplane or the nearplane.

Comment: I think @BDL has the right answer.

Comment: @BDL I see. So would you then recommend that I change the values in frustum? I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what would be the best way in going about fixing this.

Comment: @BDL I assumed that because my bmp image files are 512 x 512, that the width, height, and length should therefore be 512. Was this a mistake?

Comment: Basically you can use all sizes you want, unless the projection fits to the size of your skybox. There is also no need to have the geometry at the same size as the resolution of the texture.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be, that the skybox is not located inside of the visible area. When looking at the definition of the projection matrix `glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);`, one sees, that along the z-axis visible values have to be between 1.5 and 20.0. But the skybox is drawn from -256.0 to 256.0, which is behind the far-plane/near-plane and gets clipped away.

There are two possible solutions for this: One can either draw a smaller skybox or increase the visible area. In general the result will be the same in both cases (at least when rendering the skybox without depth-testing as first object, which one would normally do).

According to the comments: There is no relation between the size of a texture in pixels and the size of the geometry. So there is no need to draw a cube with side length of 512.

Comment: I see. So to implement the solution would I then just change the values of frustum? What values would be the most reasonable to use?

Comment: At least something that is bigger than 256

Answer (score 0):

Several things seem wonrg:

- glClear is called without the GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT but depth-test is enabled
- gluLookAt uses (0,0,0) for both eye position and point of interest, the modelview matrix won't look good; you should use the center of the box for position and whatever you want for target.
- Your display function is reloading the images and recreating the textures every frame! This should really be done just once and for all at startup time, in your init() function.
- You don't need to enable GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S or GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T because *you* *are* *providing* texture coords.
- What @BDL said: the far clipping plane is too close (20.0) considering the size of your box (512.0).

Comment: Okay thank you! I moved the methods creating the textures into init(). I also cleared the GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT and got rid of the extra enables. Those did not fix the problem however. I'm sure @BDL is correct that the values are incorrect. I'm messing around with those now to get it right, but I'm not sure exactly how I should go about fixing them.

Comment: Try 1024.0 for far clipping plane. Also, did you fix the gluLookAt call?